# Microsoft access: Search three tables and show unmatched item

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2016

Currently working on a school project and would like some help. I have 3 different tables:

1. Fund data
2. Email tracking
3. Meetings

I am trying to locate all Funds (from Fund data table) that we have not emailed or met before (these come from the Email tracking and Meetings tab respectively).

As I am a novice, I tried solving it using query criteria such as this but to no avail:

```
<>[Email tracking].[Fund name] Or <>[Meetings].[Fund name]
```

Attached is the screenshot of my query as well as my relationship view.

Thank you for your time.

**Query**
[image]

**Relationship**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you for looking something like

```
select * from fundtable where fundName not in  (select fundName from EmailTable)
or fundName not in (Select fundName from emailTable)
```

Comment: Yes I am looking for something like that, how should I go about it?

Comment: Yes I am looking for something like that, how should I go about it? Would i be something like this `Select * from [Fund data] where [Fund data]![Fund name] not in (select [Fund data]![Fund name] from [email tracking]) or [Fund data]![Fund name] not in (Select [Fund data]![Fund name] from [meetings])`   ? I trying inserting this into the query portion but it says the syntax of the subquery in his expression is incorrect.